# Pyspark: get count of rows between a time window

Tags: pyspark

I have some data in this format:

```py
user_id | date         | app_opened
123     | 2018-09-01   | 1
123     | 2018-09-01   | 1
123     | 2018-09-01   | 1
234     | 2018-08-23   | 1
234     | 2018-08-23   | 1
234     | 2018-08-21   | 1
234     | 2018-08-10   | 1
```

I am trying to get the count of the app opened in one day and also the count of app opened over the last week from the current day.

This is my required output:

```py
user_id | date         | app_opened | app_open_day | app_open_week
123     | 2018-09-01   | 1          | 1            | 1
123     | 2018-09-01   | 1          | 2            | 2
123     | 2018-09-01   | 1          | 3            | 3
234     | 2018-08-23   | 1          | 1            | 1
234     | 2018-08-23   | 1          | 2            | 2
234     | 2018-08-21   | 1          | 1            | 3
234     | 2018-08-10   | 1          | 1            | 1
```

I am using window function in pyspark to get the required output. I am successful in getting the `app_open_day` count but I am not getting the correct `app_open_week` count.

Here is my query:

```py
# For app_open_day
w1 = Window.partitionBy('user_id','date','app_opened').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)
df = df.select(col("*"), F.sum('app_opened').over(w1).alias("app_open_day"))

# For app_open_week
days = lambda i: i * 86400
w2 = (Window.partitionBy('user_id','date','app_opened').orderBy(date).rangeBetween(-days(7), 0))
df = df.select(col("*"), F.sum('app_opened').over(w2).alias("app_open_week"))
```

I am not getting where I am wrong. Please help. TIA.

Comment: @pissall app_open_day is working fine for me, but not the app_open_week.

Comment: Why have you put the Window definition inside brackets? Also, the date column had been converted to date?

Comment: If there are dates like 2018-08-16, 2018-08-17. How does app_open_week work? which group should these days involve?

Comment: @AliYesilli the data we have has been sorted as per the dates and users. So it would always be that for a user, the most recent transaction would be the first.

Comment: You can do a `rowsBetween(-7, 0)`

Comment: @pissall I was experimenting with various combinations during which in one of the case I put the window inside brackets. But removing that also doesn't help. Yes, date column has been converted to date. I did it something like this:

F.to_date(unix_timestamp(col('date'),'yyyy-MM-dd').cast("timestamp")).cast('long')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find solution for app_open_week field

```py
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> 
>>> df = sc.parallelize([
...     (123,'2018-09-01',1),
...     (123,'2018-09-01',1),
...     (123,'2018-09-01',1),
...     (234,'2018-08-23',1),
...     (234,'2018-08-23',1),
...     (234,'2018-08-21',1),
...     (234,'2018-08-10',1)
...     ]).toDF(['user_id','date','app_opened'])
>>> 
>>> window1 = Window.partitionBy('user_id')
>>> df = df.withColumn('max_date', F.max('date').over(window1))
>>> df = df.withColumn('date_diff', (F.datediff(F.to_date('max_date'),F.to_date('date'))/7).cast('integer'))
>>> 
>>> window2 = Window.partitionBy('user_id','date_diff').orderBy(F.desc('date'))
>>> df = df.withColumn('app_open_week', F.row_number().over(window2)).select('user_id','date','app_opened','app_open_week')
>>> 
>>> df.sort(["user_id", "date"], ascending=[1, 0]).show()
+-------+----------+----------+-------------+                                   
|user_id|      date|app_opened|app_open_week|
+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
|    123|2018-09-01|         1|            1|
|    123|2018-09-01|         1|            2|
|    123|2018-09-01|         1|            3|
|    234|2018-08-23|         1|            1|
|    234|2018-08-23|         1|            2|
|    234|2018-08-21|         1|            3|
|    234|2018-08-10|         1|            1|
+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I like your idea to get the `max_date` per user_id and group by on the week since (`data_diff`). However, when you add the row `(234,'2018-08-15',1)` for example, the solution is not correct anymore because you don't get the count of app opened over the last week **from the current day** but the count for the 
number of week since the `max_date`.

Comment: @pansen I think it works if you add the row (234,'2018-08-15',1). I used date_diff for grouping weeks. And in the calculation date differences divide to 7 so results are 0,1,2,3.. etc. if you look to order by clause in window2, it uses date field. I hope I could explain it

Comment: Right, you get the weeks 0, 1, 2, 3 since max date of user id but not the week **from the current day**. When having the row `(234,'2018-08-15',1)` added, I get a count of 2 for 2018-08-10 which is not correct because it is the first date which has no past dates to sum up with.

Comment: @pansen, there are two weeks, first one (23-22-21-20-19-18-17), second one is (16-15-14-13-12-11-10). So if you add the row (234,'2018-08-15',1), it will belong to second week. There will two rows for second week. (234,'2018-08-15',1) and (234,'2018-08-10',1). So you should get a count of 2 for 2018-08-10. Because it is the expected result. I ordered the group descending. If you want opposite you should change orderBy(F.desc('date')) to orderBy('date') in windows2. Then it will be 1

Comment: I understand how your solution works. All I'm saying is that it does not answer what OP is asking for. Still, I like your approach.